# Fetch table column value on user login from another script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a header script which runs some user check etc. One of those checks is his username his privileges and number of answers left.

this is that script called header.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['activeUser']))
{
 $activeUser=$_SESSION['activeUser'];
 $activeUserName=$_SESSION['activeUserName'];
 $activeUserType=$_SESSION['activeUserType'];
 $activeUserId=$_SESSION['activeUserId'];
 $odgovori=$_SESSION['preostaliOdgovori'];

}


   if(isset($_SESSION['activeUser']))
 {

    echo "<div style='float: right;'>";
    echo "<h3>Prijavljeni ste kao: ".$_SESSION['activeUser']."</h3>";
    echo "<h3>Prava: ".$_SESSION['tipNaziv']."</h3>";
    echo "<h3>Preostali odgovori: ".$odgovori."</h3>";
    echo"</div>"; 
}
else
{
    echo "<h3 style='float: right;'>Niste prijavljeni!</h3>";
}
```

So I want to read preostaliOdgovori from another script (preostaliOdgovori is table column) mojaTvrtka.php is a script where this is happening

```
$connect = connectDB();
$query ="SELECT pitanje.pitanje_id,naslov,pitanje.tvrtka_id, tvrtka.tvrtka_id,preostaliOdgovori ,
    zaposlenik.tvrtka_id,korisnik_id
    FROM pitanje 
    INNER JOIN tvrtka ON tvrtka.tvrtka_id = pitanje.tvrtka_id
    INNER JOIN zaposlenik ON zaposlenik.tvrtka_id = pitanje.tvrtka_id
    WHERE korisnik_id = '$activeUserId'";



if(isset($_SESSION['activeUser']))
{
$query1="SELECT tvrtka.tvrtka_id,preostaliOdgovori,zaposlenik.tvrtka_id,korisnik_id
    FROM tvrtka
    INNER JOIN zaposlenik ON zaposlenik.tvrtka_id = tvrtka.tvrtka_id
    WHERE korisnik_id = '$activeUserId'";

$result2=queryDB($connect,$query1);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
 {
   $odgovori=$row['preostaliOdgovori'];
 }
}
$_SESSION['preostaliOdgovori']=$odgovori;
```

All of this actually works but only when I manually load mojaTvrtka.php. I would like to make it that when a user logs in this number is automatically printed in header.php but all I get is undefined index. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your flow you need to include `mojaTvrtka.php` so that it happens before `header.php` gets loaded and then the `$_SESSION` data is available. You could probably just do `include_once('../PATH/TO/mojaTvrtka.php');` at the top.

If you included that file at the top of `header.php` it probably would work. But something you should be aware of is if you include this in every `header.php`, won't every page run this SQL code? You should have it so your code checks to make sure the `$_SESSION['preostaliOdgovori']` doesn't already exist before including it.

Comment: I allready tried including mojaTvrtka.php to header but the whole thing falls apart then

Comment: what does "whole thing fall aparts" entail? errors?

Comment: I get cannot declare connectDB which is my database connection function  so i cant even open mojaTvrtka and header gets all messed up (parts of mojaTvrtka are shown in header)

Comment: I var_dumped $odgovori in header and mojaTvrtka and at firsr in header its NULL and when i click href to moja tvrtka var_dump on mojaTvrtka is string (1) "0" but header is still NULL and when i click mojaTvrtka again session gets filled and value in header gets filled.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing session in a variable and trying to call variable in another page using variable,

As session are global variable you can call $_SESSION['activeUserId'] in mojaTvrtka.php pass directly into mysqlquery like below.

```
$query ="SELECT pitanje.pitanje_id,naslov,pitanje.tvrtka_id, tvrtka.tvrtka_id,preostaliOdgovori ,
    zaposlenik.tvrtka_id,korisnik_id
    FROM pitanje 
    INNER JOIN tvrtka ON tvrtka.tvrtka_id = pitanje.tvrtka_id
    INNER JOIN zaposlenik ON zaposlenik.tvrtka_id = pitanje.tvrtka_id
    WHERE korisnik_id = $_SESSION['activeUserId']";
```

Comment: Im not sure what are you trying to tell me. Im trying to transfer value from preostaliOdgovori from that second query on my page